# How to use KaGaPa Phonetics input method in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-xp, keyboard-layout

I frequently use KaGaPa phonetics layout input method in Linux. But I unable to use it in Windows operating system. How can I use KaGaPa in Windows same like as Linux.
**Here I can't find KaGaPa Phonetics Keyboard Layout.**

[image]

 **Also I try to find it from Input_Language_List but KaGaPa also not Present there.**
[image]

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/indic-keyboards/

Comment: @DavidPostill How to install and setup it like Linux. I was use google Input Tool but how to configure KaGaPa  I don't know.

Comment: I've no idea. Perhaps the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/indic-keyboards/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I use KaGaPa in Windows same like as Linux.

There is an [open source project](https://www.openhub.net/p/indic-keyboards) providing many Indic scripts to be used on Windows, including KaGaPa.

> An open source project providing an input method which will allow the usage of Indic scripts on both Windows and Linux, using Java and Unicode.
>
> KaGaPa, Tamil99, Inscript, Remington are some of the popular keyboard layouts supported along with QWERTY phonetic input. (like Baraha, Mylai etc.)
>
> New keyboard layouts can be added by using an easy interface.

Source [A Multilingual Unicode Input Method for Windows and Linux](https://code.google.com/p/indic-keyboards/)

Comment: ok I try it first.

Comment: but one problem also there is no KaGaPa layout for Marathi and Hindi

Answer (score 1):

Found that the chosen answer is defunct as of now. I made a layout that emulates Ubuntu Linux's Devanagari KaGaPa phonetic keyboard [here](https://github.com/srix55/sanskrit-kagapa-windows). It's simple to alter the layout with [Microsoft's Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134), using a base source file (klc extension).